# return all row after call stored procedure in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

The following stored procedure has been created in the database, stored procedure works correctly in database:

```
create procedure [dbo].[search_pazhoheshgar]
@se_code_melli varchar(10) = NULL,
@se_name nvarchar(30) = NULL,
@se_family nvarchar(30) = NULL,
@se_name_uni nvarchar(100) = NULL,
@se_name_reshte_tahsili nvarchar(50) = NULL
AS
begin try
begin tran
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select sabt.code_melli, sabt.name, sabt.family, sabt_como_univercity.name_uni,
sabt_como_reshte.name_reshte_tahsili
from sabt 
inner join sabt_como_univercity ON sabt.univercity = sabt_como_univercity.id_uni
inner join sabt_como_reshte ON sabt.name_reshte = sabt_como_reshte.id_reshte_tahsili
where 
sabt.code_melli like '%' + @se_code_melli + '%' or 
sabt.name like '%' + @se_name + '%' or  
sabt.family like '%' + @se_family + '%' or
sabt_como_univercity.name_uni like '%' + @se_name_uni + '%' or
sabt_como_reshte.name_reshte_tahsili like '%' + @se_name_reshte_tahsili + '%'
commit tran
end try
begin catch
rollback tran
return -1
end catch
```

With the commands below, I want to run stored procedure from C# program :

```
SqlParameter[] sqlParams;
string sqlQuery;
sqlQuery = "search_pazhoheshgar @se_code_melli, @se_name, @se_family, @se_name_uni, @se_name_reshte_tahsili";

sqlParams = new SqlParameter[]
        {
new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@se_code_melli",  Value = (object)textBox23.Text ?? DBNull.Value},
new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@se_name",  Value = (object)textBox22.Text ?? DBNull.Value},
new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@se_family",  Value = (object)textBox21.Text ?? DBNull.Value},
new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@se_name_uni",  Value = (object)comboBox11.Text ?? DBNull.Value},
new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@se_name_reshte_tahsili",  Value = (object)comboBox12.Text ?? DBNull.Value}
        };

using (SamenEntities dbContext = new SamenEntities())
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<search_pazhoheshgar_Result>(sqlQuery, sqlParams).ToList();
}
```

But after running all the existing rows are displayed from the database. Also, I used the following Way to run stored procedure. But again, all rows are displayed:

```
using (SamenEntities dbContext = new SamenEntities())
    {
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dbContext.search_pazhoheshgar(textBox23.Text, textBox22.Text, textBox21.Text, comboBox11.Text, comboBox12.Text);
    }
```

How can I fix the searcher problem?

Comment: try to trace the query

Comment: Is any of the text boxes empty? If yes, you will have a comparison like `sabt.name like '%%'`, which, combined with the `or`, will always yield the entire result set (except when the respective column is `NULL`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query combines a check on the search criteria with an `OR` condition. That means, when only one of entries an empty string, you will get the entire result set (except when the respective column is `NULL`).

Your expression `Value = (object)textBox23.Text ?? DBNull.Value` will never yield `DBNull`, because `TextBox.Text` will have the value `""` instead of `null`. So you will pass an empty string to your stored procedure, which will cause...

```
abt.code_melli LIKE '%' + @se_code_melli + '%'
```

...to evaluate to...

```
abt.code_melli LIKE '%%'
```

Which will yield the entire result set (except where the column contains a `NULL` value), no matter what is in your other parameters (because they are combined with `OR`).

You have to guard yourself against that in your `WHERE` condition:

```
--[...]
WHERE 
    @se_code_melli IS NOT NULL AND @se_code_melli <> '' AND
        sabt.code_melli LIKE '%' + @se_code_melli + '%' OR 
    @se_name IS NOT NULL AND @se_name <> '' AND sabt.name LIKE '%' + @se_name + '%' OR  
    --[...]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Are the two methods that presented, differ? In both, it works properly.

Comment: In the second method, it is used `search_pazhoheshgar_Result` (complex type)